# Getting prestashop custom webservice item

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In the way to develop my custom module, I've created new custom webservice. I managed to get a list of items but what I'm looking now is to get each item individually.

This is the definition of the class used for my custom webservice:

```
public static $definition = [
   'table'     => 'centralized_stores',
   'primary'   => 'id_centralizedstore',
   'fields'    => [
        'store_name'            => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 256],
        'store_url'             => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUrl', 'size' => 2038],
        'store_api_key'         => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 32],
        'store_contact_email'   => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'size' => 254],
    ]
];
```

This block is the webservice definition parameters:

```
protected $webserviceParameters = [
    'objectNodeName' =>'store',
    'objectsNodeName' =>'centralized_store',
    'associations' => [
        'storeDetails' =>[
            'resource' => 'storeDetails',
            'getter' => 'getStoreDetails',
            'setter' => false,
            'virtual_entity' => true,
            'fields' => [
                'store_name' =>  [],
                'store_url' => [],
                'store_api_key' =>  [],
                'store_contact_Email' =>  [],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I need to know how webservice URL's work. I mean, when I go to http://dev.prestashop.local/tienda-base/api/centralized_store/1 how to associate with a function inside my class. Then I'll need to know how to develope a class to insert new store details into my custom table by url such as http://dev.prestashop.local/tienda-base/api/centralized_store/store_name=thename&store_url=theurl...

Edit 3: I've clean some tips and code for this question. Hope this should be cleaner now.

Comment: Added some information, don't know how to implement custom CRUD functions by passing url parameters.

Comment: No one can help me? =(